# How can I redefine the chapter command to display additional text below the title?

Tags: macros, sectioning, memoir

I'm relatively inexperienced with Latex. I'm using the Memoir class and I've been trying to develop a custom chapter style based on Danie Els' BlueBox style (the source for this is given on page 46 of [Memoir Chapter Styles](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/info/latex-samples/MemoirChapStyles/MemoirChapStyles.pdf)).

I'd like to redefine the chapter command to take two arguments, such as below:

```
\chapter{ExampleChapter}{A short description of the contents of this chapter}
```

I'd then like to have both arguments passed to a redefined version of \printchaptertitle so that I can print the description beneath the title:

```
\renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[2]{%
\usebox{\ChpNumBox}\hfill
\parbox[t]{\hsize-\wd\ChpNumBox-1em}{%
\vspace{\midchapskip}%
\thickhrulefill\par
\chaptitlefont ##1\par}}%2
% ##2 is used somewhere here
}
```

**EDIT**

I hacked something ugly together that's pretty close to what I want:

I redefine the afterchapskip length within the chapter style to be negative:

```
\setlength{\afterchapskip}{-45pt}
```

I then define the following macro:

```
\newcommand{\addChapter}[2] {
\chapter{#1}
\begin{flushright}
\parbox[t]{\hsize-\wd\ChpNumBox-5em}{\flushright\small{\textcolor{dark-gray}{#2}}}
\end{flushright}
\vspace{30pt}
}
```

Then within the document itself I use:

```
\addChapter{Example Chapter}{A short description of the contents of this chapter. I can ramble on a bit just to point out that this is flushed right.}
```

That produces the following:

[image]

**EDIT 2**

Using daleif's recommended approach below, I've got something that works quite nicely.

I define the following:

```
\def\chapterDesc{}
%...
\newcommand{\setChapterDescription}[1]{%
\def\chapterDesc{#1}%
}
%...
\newcommand{\addChapter}[2]{
\setChapterDescription{#2}
\chapter{#1}
\setChapterDescription{}
}
%...
\renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
\usebox{\ChpNumBox}\hfill
\parbox[t]{\hsize-\wd\ChpNumBox-1em}{%
\vspace{\midchapskip}%
\thickhrulefill\par
\chaptitlefont ##1\par
\vspace{20pt}
\normalfont\small\textcolor{dark-gray}{\chapterDesc}}
}%2
}
```

I can then do something like the following:

```
\addChapter{Example Chapter}{A short description of the contents of this chapter. I can ramble on a bit just to point out that this is flushed right.}
```

[image]

Or just:

```
\chapter{Descriptionless Chapter}
```

[image]

Comment: You do not need `\setChapterDescription{}` in `\addChapter`, just add `\gdef\chapterDesc{}` at the end of `\printchaptertitle`. And next time, please post full minimal examples, including preamble and such. That makes it a lot easier for people to use or test your suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would take a lot of work. It would be easier to use a two macro approach.

I usually do this independently of `\chapter` using `\chapterprecis`.

If you wanted it directly into the chapter style it might be better to use an approach like

```
\setchapterdesc{....}
\chapter{....}
```

and then let the chapter style use the macro that the imaginary macro `\setchapterdesc` stores its value in (remember to globally clear it after use)

Comment: Thanks! Using global variables had crossed my mind, though I wasn't sure about how they're used within Latex. I'm guessing defining setChapterDesc to something like "\def\chapterDesc{#1}" should work, and then I just use \chapterDesc within \printchaptertitle. I'll try this out!